# Why does a double digit selection not return the correct response in python?

Tags: python, task

I'm learning how to use python right now.  I found a problem while learning about definitions that I don't understand.  I give a simple menu with choice 0-4. If the user chooses above 4, there supposed to receive a message that says "This is not a valid choice..."

However, if you input a value greater than or equal to 10, it doesn't return anything but the menu...no message.

Thanks in Advance for Any Thoughts.

Here is My Code:

```
# Multitasker
# Allows User to Pick an Item that is Defined.

def exit():
    print("See You Later!")
def task1():
    print("This is Task 1!")
def task2():
    print("This is Task 2!")
def task3():
    print("This is Task 3!")
def task4():
    print("This is Task 4!")

choice = None
while choice != "0":
    print(
        """
        Multitask Selector

        0 - Quit
        1 - Task 1
        2 - Task 2
        3 - Task 3
        4 - Task 4
        """
        )

    choice = input("Pick a Task Between 1-4:\t#")
    print()

    # Exit
    if choice == "0":
        exit()

    # Task 1
    elif choice == "1":
        task1()

    # Task 2
    elif choice == "2":
        task2()

    # Task 3
    elif choice == "3":
        task3()

    # Task 4
    elif choice == "4":
        task4()

    # Not a Correct Selection
    elif choice > "4":
        print("That is not a valid choice.  Please Select a Task Between 1-4.")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're comparing choice, which is a string (I'm assuming Python 3 from your print functions), with "4", also a string.

```
elif choice > "4":
```

This works lexicographically:

```
>>> '1' < '2'
True
>>> '1' < '100'
True
>>> '100' < '2'
True
```

If you want numerical comparisons, you have to turn choice into a number, e.g.

```
>>> int('1') > 4
False
>>> int('10') > 4
True
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was what I was thinking it was, but didn't know how to do it, yet.  Now I do though!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"10" is not greater than "4". Both are strings and are compared character-by-character. "1" is less than "4" so "10" is less than "4". What you should do is convert them to integers:

```
choice = input("Pick a Task Between 1-4:\t#")
choice = int(choice) if choice.isdigit() else 9  # add this line
```

This converts any non-numeric entry to 9 so it'll display the menu again.

Then compare with numbers instead of strings:

```
if choice == 0:
    exit()
```

Your last condition can simply be `else`, you needn't use `elif` there.

Comment: Do you mean else for choice > int('4') or else for everything after the if statement?  So can all the elif's be changed to else's?  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, the last one: `choice > "4"`. If none of the other ones match, you want to print the message; it doesn't really matter what the choice was, does it?

Comment: I tried adding else and when I ran it, it said choice was an invalid syntax.

Comment: That tells me you just put it in in front of what you already had. That whole last `eilf` line can just be `else:`.